# Relative paths for git-svn SVN authors file?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I have cloned an SVN repository from work using git-svn. During the initial cloning, I provided an SVN authors file. When I did the initial clone, git set the `authorsfile` as an absolute path. However,  I keep copies of this git repository on a work machine and a laptop, and keep the copies in sync using [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) (they are not two different clones, but the same clone).

The paths to my git repository are different on the work machine and the laptop, which means that the authors file won't be found on the work machine, where the absolute path is invalid. Will git-svn accept a relative path for the `authorsfile`, instead, so that the authors file will always be found and I can safely run `git svn rebase` and `git snv dcommit` from either machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When I did the initial clone, git set the authorsfile as an absolute path.

You can change it to a relative path. If you open `.git/config` file in vim or any text editor you can edit it relative to the `.git` folder.

By doing this this should allow you to use the same `authors` file in all your machine.

Comment: Thanks. It's worth noting that the path is relative to the root directory of the repository (i.e., the directory containing the `.git` subdirectory).